# TSQL - How do I aggregate timestamp intervals for one particular pattern of occurence in a data set?

Tags: t-sql

I have the rather challenging task of building a query from a data set off logged status changes, where I need to find and aggregate the spans between two different statuses for a given record id, but the occurrence of that pattern is both variable in occurrence and inconsistent.

However, I can't imagine this hasn't been done before.  What I'm looking for is a pointer in the right direction as to what SQL techniques ought to be used to extract this information.

Here's an example of what the data set is like:

```
id  status  datetime
1001    A   1/1/15 12:00 PM
1001    B   1/1/15 1:00 PM
1001    C   1/1/15 2:00 PM
1001    D   1/1/15 3:00 PM
1001    B   1/1/15 4:00 PM
1001    C   1/1/15 5:00 PM
1001    D   1/1/15 6:00 PM
1002    A   1/1/15 12:00 PM
1002    B   1/1/15 1:00 PM
1002    C   1/1/15 2:00 PM
1002    D   1/1/15 3:00 PM
1003    A   1/1/15 12:00 PM
1003    B   1/1/15 1:00 PM
1003    C   1/1/15 2:00 PM
1003    B   1/1/15 3:00 PM
1003    C   1/1/15 4:00 PM
1003    D   1/1/15 5:00 PM
1004    A   1/1/15 12:00 PM
1004    B   1/1/15 2:00 PM
1004    A   1/1/15 3:00 PM
1004    B   1/1/15 4:00 PM
1004    C   1/1/15 5:00 PM
1004    D   1/1/15 6:00 PM
```

In this scenario, I'm trying to find the sum of all time spans between any status B to status C change for each record id.   As you can see, that pattern happens sometimes once, sometimes never, sometimes multiple times, and sometimes only partially (A to B back to A for instance, which would not be counted)

So conceptually, the output I'm looking for would look like this:

```
id      total b-c minutes
1001    120
1002    60
1003    120
1004    60
```

My actual data is not so neatly cut into 1 hour chunks, of course.

I'm more of a programmer than a database person.  I could do something iterative in C# easily, but I'm trying to learn what techniques would be used in SQL to perform the same task?

Comment: Unless you are using SQL Server 2012 and later, which has `LAG` and `LEAD` functions, you'd better implement this processing in C#. In C# you can do it with a `O(n)` algorithm (after the initial data is sorted), in SQL without `LAG/LEAD` you'll end up with `O(n*n)`.

Comment: Vladimir, where should I go to learn more about the appropriate use of C# vs T-SQL when doing reporting?

Comment: This is a very broad question. Traditionally RDBMS works with `relations` of **unordered** `sets`. So if the problem can be solved in terms of `relational algebra`, then SQL is a good choice. If you start thinking about sequences and processing elements of a set in a particular order, it means that procedural approach is likely better. Recent updates to SQL standard added `window functions`, which help in many cases, but if the task is more complex than simple lookup of next/previous element of the ordered set, it again may be better to use procedural approach. Watch the link in @gordy answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with TB as ( /* get the B rows and the timestamp of the next status */
    select
        id, status, tstamp,
        (
            select min(tstamp) from T as t2
            where t2.id = t1.id and t2.tstamp > t1.tstamp
        ) as next_tstamp
    from T as t1
    where status = 'B'
)
select id, sum(datediff(ss, tstamp, next_tstamp)) /* or some other timespan function */
from TB as tb
where /* check that next status is a C. assumes tstamp is unique per id */
    (select status from T where T.id = TB.id and T.tstamp = TB.next_tstamp) = 'C'
group by id
```

A SQL Server 2008 option with `CROSS APPLY`

```
select t1.id, sum(datediff(ss, t1.tstamp, t2.tstamp))
from
    T as t1 cross apply
    (
    select top 1 status, tstamp /* using top is non-standard */
    from T as t2
    where t2.id = t1.id and t2.tstamp > t1.tstamp
    order by tstamp desc
    ) as t2
where t1.status = 'B' and t2.status = 'C'
group by t1.id
```

Comment: I was able to implement this answer, without CROSS APPLY (first example)

Comment: Also to note, I'd probably be using the LAG/LEAD answer if I had 2014.

Comment: Then I guess you're a lucky guy to have somebody write you a couple versions that work without it.

Comment: Yeah all in all, every response here is workable.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

This is a good candidate for using a windowing function. Here's one way to do it:

```
with
    b_to_c_transitions as
    (select id, status, datetime c_time,
     lag(datetime) over (partition by id order by datetime) b_time
     from logtable where status in ('B','C'))

select id, sum(datediff(minute, b_time, c_time))
from b_to_c_transitions where status='C' group by id
```

Comment: My impression was that the B and C rows must occur in sequence. Your query would filter for any rows with status B or C and then pair them up after that filtering has been accomplished. I believe that returns many more pairing than were intended by OP.

Comment: the query assumes that C can only be preceded by B, which seems like a safe assumption given the example. if not then just an additional criteria is needed in b_to_c_transitions

Comment: I don't disagree that this is a perfect opportunity to use lag(). I thought adding that example too. Every time I write something that the mysql guys don't have like they start downvoting me.

Comment: that's awful. reminded me of this great presentation on modern language features not adopted by mysql - http://www.slideshare.net/MarkusWinand/modern-sql

Comment: I like this answer because I learned I need to update to 2014 for concrete reasons.  However in this instance I used the subsequent answer.

Comment: @user1910915 lag is supported as of 2012 but you may as well go to 2014 if you need to upgrade